# Get all href that match a specific path in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to grab all the href from a webpage and attach them as clickable links, but I am not sure how to grab them. I am trying to grab hrefs that follow this format

```
<table class="imageList">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="build/artifacts/image1.png">One</a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="build/artifacts/image2.png">Two</a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="build/artifacts/image3.png">Three</a> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

etc...

All images have the href prefix build/artifacts/ and are inside of the table "imageList", but how do I grab all of them (the hrefs). I am only interested in the hrefs and not the whole table or other non  elements that may exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CSS Attribute Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```
'table.imageList > tbody > tr > td > a[href^="build/artifacts/"]'
```

Then use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
anchors = document.querySelectorAll('table.imageList > tbody > tr > td > a[href^="build/artifacts/"]');
```

Finally, you might [iterate over the result set and extract the hrefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Example:_using_map_generically):

```
hrefs = Array.prototype.map.call(anchors, function(item) { return item.getAttribute('href'); } );
```

[Credits for the Array.prototype.map goes to Vohuman; I included his idea to provide a complete solution]

Comment: Please care, `jQuery` was not tagged.

Comment: Sorry, you can also use getElementsBySelector. It is the same API.

Comment: Please don't reference links from w3schools. They are often outdated and incorrect. Best to use official documentation like MDN.

Comment: `getElementsBySelector` is this something that you found on w3schools?

Comment: Links from w3schools are never outdated and incorrect. More than that, for more than a decade at top of all search engines (with a reason).

Comment: Point was, use the right css selector as presented. Then use your favorite API function. If it is jQuery or something else does not matter.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect discussion.

Comment: Point is `Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.`

Comment: Not my wish, merely stating the info. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript comes with a method called [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) that you can use to grab the `<a></a>` tags and store them in an array.  Then you can extract their `href` properties in a for-loop.

Try this:

```
var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var hrefs = [];
for(var i =0; i < anchor.length; i++){
  hrefs.push(anchor[i].href;
}
```

Libraries like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) also exist to make these kinds of operations more semantic and readable, however these libraries are ultimately built up from their vanilla JavaScript counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('table.imageList a[href^="build"]');
var hrefArr = Array.prototype.map.call(anchors, function(el) {
   // `el.href` returns the absolute path
   return el.getAttribute('href');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery.

```
    $("a").each(function() {
      $(this).attr('href'); 
   });
```